# WCF service communicating with web app client and android client

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I'm new to the community, I hope I'm asking right.

I have a WCF service that should receive connections from both "web app client" and "Android app".

Is it possible to do this?
As I understood the best way to connect to Android is using JSON, but how can I manage the connection to the web app?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide any more specifics? What type of data will you be exchanging with the clients?

Comment: WCF uses the standard SOAP protocol, as long as what you are calling it conforms to that protocol, you will be good to go.

Comment: But SOAP is less connection reliable, no?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is right!

(i)Yes it is possible, since wcf services can be consumed by both web and android app.

(ii)You can either use SOAP/JSON for android and web app, your connections can be maintained in the web.config.

Comment: Can you give me some example how do I configure the connection? Is this one service configuration ? The thing is I already have a web client that uses binding="wsHttpBinding" and binding="mexHttpBinding". If I choose JSON (binding="webHttpBinding") should I change my web client? I appreciate you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use WCF for both web client as well as android, I would suggest you to use Restful WCF as Android does not support Soap by default.